# What are best practices to override complete sections using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose

The docker-compose.override contains:

```
volumes:
  - ./a:/path/to/a
```

The docker-compose:

```
volumes:
  - a:/path/to/a
```

When docker-compose up is run the override overwrite the `./a` overwrites the `a`.

When a new volume is added to docker-compose, the override will try to mount is as well.

docker-compose.override

```
volumes:
  - ./a:/path/to/a
```

The docker-compose:

```
volumes:
  - a:/path/to/a
  - b:/path/to/b
```

How to prevent that the override will use volumes that are defined in the docker-compose file?

When docker-compose.override contains

```
volumes:
  - a:/path/to/a
  - .b:/path/to/b
```

the b is still mounted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [to this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files) it does not seem to be possible to override complete sections in docker-compose by using different docker-compose files.

> If both files are present on the same directory level, Compose
>   combines the two files into a single configuration.
>
> The configuration in the docker-compose.override.yml file is applied
>   over and in addition to the values in the docker-compose.yml file.